# How to show the shipping and handling fee directly on the cart total?

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, shipping, shipping-methods, totals

I have only one shipping method - Table rate on which I calculate two different aspects.

1. for over $200 - shipping price will be $0.00 that is free.
2. below $200 is $9.50.

Now I get these calculation processed only after I trigger estimate shipping form or co-shipping form. Is that possible to load the shipping fee automatically once the page loads? and show up the result on cart total box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just send the co-shipping-method-form details via ajax submission on page load. this helped me to calculate the shipping Fee automatically without the estimate shipping and update total things. code what I used to trigger the form is below hope this will help someone.. also if this method is not good to use please guide me on this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        (function($){
            $(document).ready(function() {

                var currentRequest = null;
                var url = "<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart/estimateUpdatePost') ?>"; // co-shipping-method-form action url.
                var data = $("#co-shipping-method-form");
                $("#process").show(); // shows loading

                currentRequest =$.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  data: data.serialize(),
                  dataType: "html",
                  url: url,
                  beforeSend : function(){           
                        if(currentRequest != null){
                            currentRequest.abort();
                        }
                   },
                  success: function(response){ 
                      //console.log(response);
                      // find element with class name .cart-totals
                      var result = $('.cart-totals', response)

                      //console.log(result);
                      // replace with original
                      $(".cart-totals-wrapper").html(result); 

                      $("#process").hide("slow"); // hide loading
                   },
                  });    
                return false;    
            });
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inorder to add shipping charge automatically to cart page, use the magento extension **https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/auto-shipping-pro.html** . Its really awesome and works like a charm. [enter link description here][1]

Answer (score 0):

The shipping totals in the cart are shown as soon as the quote has a shipping address with country and a shipping method has been selected, because the calculation is based on the country and there might be different methods available.

You need to add a dummy address with the default country and automatically select the first available shipping address when on the cart page.

We have an open source extension on GitHub for this: https://github.com/integer-net/AutoShipping

It also solves quite some special cases, like shipping rates that depend on the items in the cart, free shipping rules etc. - too much to fit into this answer.

Answer (score 0):

For that you have to work with observer and  used `checkout_cart_save_after` event and paste this below code in the observer file that you created:

```
private $_shippingCode = 'flatrate_flatrate';
private $_country = 'GB';

public function addShipping($params = null) {
    if (Mage::registry('checkout_addShipping')) {
        Mage::unregister('checkout_addShipping');
        return;
    }

    Mage::register('checkout_addShipping',true);

    $cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
    //zend_debug::dump($cart->getData());exit;
    $quote = $cart->getQuote();

    if ($quote->getCouponCode() != '') {
        $c = Mage::getResourceModel('salesrule/rule_collection');
        $c->getSelect()->where("code=?", $quote->getCouponCode());
        foreach ($c->getItems() as $item) { $coupon = $item; }

        if ($coupon->getSimpleFreeShipping() > 0) {
            $quote->getShippingAddress()->setShippingMethod($this->_shippingCode)->save();
            return true;
        }
    }

    try {

        //$method = $quote->getShippingAddress()->getShippingMethod();

        //if ($method) return; // don't overwrite what's already there if we have one set already

        if ($quote->getShippingAddress()->getCountryId() == '') {
            $quote->getShippingAddress()->setCountryId($this->_country);
        }

        $quote->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true);
        $quote->getShippingAddress()->collectShippingRates();

        $rates = $quote->getShippingAddress()->getAllShippingRates();
        $allowed_rates = array();
        foreach ($rates as $rate) {
            array_push($allowed_rates,$rate->getCode());
        }

        if (!in_array($this->_shippingCode,$allowed_rates) && count($allowed_rates) > 0) {
            $shippingCode = $allowed_rates[0];
        }

        //zend_debug::dump(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getGrandTotal());exit;
        //if(Mage::helper('checkout')->getQuote()->getData('subtotal')<=49){
            $totals = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getTotals();
            $finaltotal = $totals["subtotal"]->getValue();

         // zend_debug::dump($sample);exit;
            //zend_debug::dump($finaltotal);exit;
            if($finaltotal<=49){
        if (!empty($shippingCode)) {
            $address = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress();
            if ($address->getCountryId() == '') $address->setCountryId($this->_country);
            if ($address->getCity() == '') $address->setCity('');
            if ($address->getPostcode() == '') $address->setPostcode('');
            if ($address->getRegionId() == '') $address->setRegionId('');
            if ($address->getRegion() == '') $address->setRegion('');
            $address->setShippingMethod($this->_shippingCode)->setCollectShippingRates(true);
            Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->save();
        } else {
            $address = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress();
            if ($address->getCountryId() == '') $address->setCountryId($this->_country);
            if ($address->getCity() == '') $address->setCity('');
            if ($address->getPostcode() == '') $address->setPostcode('');
            if ($address->getRegionId() == '') $address->setRegionId('');
            if ($address->getRegion() == '') $address->setRegion('');
            $address->setShippingMethod($this->_shippingCode)->setCollectShippingRates(true);
            Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->save();
        }
    }
        else{

                if (!empty($shippingCode)) {
            $address = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress();
            if ($address->getCountryId() == '') $address->setCountryId($this->_country);
            if ($address->getCity() == '') $address->setCity('');
            if ($address->getPostcode() == '') $address->setPostcode('');
            if ($address->getRegionId() == '') $address->setRegionId('');
            if ($address->getRegion() == '') $address->setRegion('');
            $address->setShippingMethod('freeshipping_freeshipping')->setCollectShippingRates(true);
            Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->save();
        } else {
            $address = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress();
            if ($address->getCountryId() == '') $address->setCountryId($this->_country);
            if ($address->getCity() == '') $address->setCity('');
            if ($address->getPostcode() == '') $address->setPostcode('');
            if ($address->getRegionId() == '') $address->setRegionId('');
            if ($address->getRegion() == '') $address->setRegion('');
            $address->setShippingMethod('freeshipping_freeshipping')->setCollectShippingRates(true);
            Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->save();
        }
        }

        Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->resetCheckout();

    }
    catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
        Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addException($e, Mage::helper('checkout')->__('Load customer quote error'));
    }


}
```

It worked for me  when  checkout cart subtotal is less than 49.

If so it displays free shipping otherwise displays flat rate charge.